# Getting the following when invoking an integer array method: Index (zero based) must be

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm learning c# for the first time and I'm struggling to understand how to invoke an integer array method in a console readout.  I'm using a role-playing game as a roadmap for design, and have been fine up until I tried to call up stats for a class to be reported through the console.

I am pulling data from this block:

```
public static int Stats(int[] stats) {
        int str, intel, dex;

        str = 1 * LevelUp();
        intel = 3 * (LevelUp() / 2);
        dex = 2 * (LevelUp() / 3);

        stats[0] = str;
        stats[1] = intel;
        stats[2] = dex;
        return stats[2];
    }
```

But I am receiving an error in the following console readout that matches the title.

```
public void HeroStateManager() {
        Mage mage = new Mage();
        Console.ReadLine();
        if (HeroClass() == "Mage") {
            int[] stats = {0,1,2};
            Console.WriteLine("You have the following stats:");
            Console.WriteLine("Intel:   {0}", Mage.Stats(stats));
            Console.WriteLine("Str:     {1}", Mage.Stats(stats));
            Console.WriteLine("Dex:     {2}", Mage.Stats(stats));
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `Stats()` method like this:

```
public static int[] Stats(int[] stats) 
{
    int str, intel, dex;

    str = 1 * LevelUp();
    intel = 3 * (LevelUp() / 2);
    dex = 2 * (LevelUp() / 3);

    stats[0] = str;
    stats[1] = intel;
    stats[2] = dex;
    return stats;
}
```

You don't even need to return anything, as `int[]` is a reference type, but returning the altered array could allow for some fluent code.

Then change the other method like this:

```
public void HeroStateManager()
{
    Mage mage = new Mage();
    // Console.ReadLine(); what was this? pausing for debugging?

    if (HeroClass() == "Mage")
    {
        int[] stats = new int[3];
        Mage.Stats(stats);

        Console.WriteLine("You have the following stats:");
        Console.WriteLine("Intel:   {0}", stats[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Str:     {0}", stats[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Dex:     {0}", stats[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hadn't read the question thoroughly. The answer is much better now.

Comment: You are a saint!  This works exactly how i intended.  Can you possibly take the time to explain to me the difference of declaring Mage.Stats(stats) outside of the console.writeline?  It feels like the same thing, just it's just written with a different dialect with the same meaning when I juxtapose the two.

Comment: Mage.Stats() does work. Why make the computer do that same work three times? Call the method once, and the results are in the stats array.

Comment: Okay, I understand much better now.  Thank you for all of your help Joel, I've been learning unhindered since I read your post.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Intel:   {0}", Mage.Stats(stats));
        Console.WriteLine("Str:     {0}", Mage.Stats(stats));
        Console.WriteLine("Dex:     {0}", Mage.Stats(stats));
```

Comment: That stops the error, but does not show the integer in relation.  All returned values are 0, rather than the integer formulas written.